# Dictionary values inside an unknown key

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I'm trying to extract some value from a dictionary, which I've converted using `json.loads()`

The issue I've got is, one of the keys is going to be unknown,, as it's an ID number. Realistically, I could hard code the ID as it's unlikely to change, but that just feels wrong. There must be a better way.

```
{
  'status': {
    'timestamp': '2020-10-27T08:11:22.182Z',
    'error_code': 0,
    'error_message': None,
    'elapsed': 11,
    'credit_count': 1,
    'notice': None
  },
  'data': {
    '1': {
      'id': 1,
```

Under id:1, way way down... there's another couple of key/values I want to extract.. but the problem is, `1` could be anything! It's just an IT number assigned by the API I'm pulling the JSON from.

If I hard code it in the `price` variable:

```
price=data['data']['1']['quote']['price']
```

...I of course, get the correct value I'm looking for.. but what I want to do is something like:

```
price=data['data']['?']['quote']['price']
```

where `?` is, 'ignore the name of the next key, just move on'

For clarity, the ID key is the only key below data... everything sits inside the ID. So is there a way to move to the next key without worrying what it's called?

Since it's a dictionary, I'd thought about using `data.items()` but that feels like a really really messy way of getting the data out.

Comment: `price = next(iter(data['data'].values()))['quote']['price']` seems reasonably simple. You are not interested in the key, so go straight to value =)

Comment: @schwobaseggl you have to convert `values()` to a list first since `dict_view` is not subscriptable. At this point I'd prefer to use `.pop` or even just a loop

Comment: @DeepSpace You are right. Just changed it. I usually prefer `next(iter(...))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will use a for loop:

```
for x in j['data']:
  print(j['data'][x]['quote']['price'])
  break
```

Comment: You can use `.values` then there is no need to repeat `j['data']`: `for v in j['data'].values(): print(v['quote']['price'])`